# Issue loading BMP image using SDL_image

Tags: c, bmp, image-loading, sdl-image

I am new to SDL_image and I am trying to use it in a C file to load a BMP image.
To that end, I have written the following code:

```
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "SDL_image.h"

SDL_RWops *rwop;
rwop = SDL_RWFromFile("sample.bmp", "rb");
```

However, for some reason, although `rwop` after those lines are executed is not `NULL` anymore, `IMG_isBMP(rwop)` is 0.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: First thing is to make sure it *is* a valid BMP file. It could have the wrong extension.

Comment: @Jongware: How do you check whether it is a valid BMP? I am using this figure for testing: http://file.fyicenter.com/a/sample.bmp

Comment: @Morpfh: I think you are right... how can I fix this?

Comment: I must have done something wrong at first. No idea what. Works fine now.

Comment: @Beginner: I used `imagemagick`. Simply `identify sample.bmp`, should yield BMP etc.

Comment: @Morph: I got the following: `sample.bmp BMP 256x256 256x256+0+0 4-bit PseudoClass 16c 32.9KB 0.000u 0:00.000` so I think it is a valid bmp, and that the problem is the 2nd reason you had mentioned previously... do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps better example. This (might) yield more information and perhaps if BMP is supported:

https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/docs/SDL_image_32.html

You could also try using `IMG_LoadBMP_RW` as per example here:

https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/docs/SDL_image_16.html#SEC16

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_image.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char *fn = "sample.bmp";
    SDL_Surface *surf;

    if (argc > 1)
        fn = argv[1];

    if ((surf = SDL_LoadBMP(fn)) == NULL) {
        printf("SDL_loadBMP failed: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("%s is bmp\n", fn);

    SDL_FreeSurface(surf);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

---

#### Old answer:

---

Tested and validated:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_image.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char *fn = "sample.bmp";
    int v;
    SDL_RWops *rwop;

    if (argc > 1)
        fn = argv[1];

    if ((rwop = SDL_RWFromFile(fn, "rb")) == NULL) {
        printf("SDL_RWFromFile failed: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }

    v = IMG_isBMP(rwop);

    printf("%s is bmp = %d\n", fn, v);

    SDL_FreeRW(rwop);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o sdl sdl.c `sdl-config --libs` -lSDL_image
```

Yield for BMP images, e.g.:

```
$ ./sdltest lena.bmp 
lena.bmp is bmp = 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, both of your examples work as expected! :) The issue remains when I compile & execute my C file though... It must be in the `CMakeLists.txt` file that I use for compiling my project. I will ask a separate question about that. Thanks for your time! :)